# Sql Query involving multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables..

**Persons:**

```
  empid(primary key)
  firstname
  lastname
  email
```

**Details:**

```
  Did(primary key)
  salary
  designation
  empid
```

Now I need to `SELECT` first name and last name of employees whose designation is `Manager`.

I am a beginner, I have been learning SQL from W3school (which is awesome btw), if you can suggest me where should I go after completing w3school that would be just great!

Comment: [Not everyone agrees about w3school!](http://w3fools.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty much as you said it, with a simple join on the column that relates the two tables together (in this case `EmpID`):

```
SELECT firstname,
       lastname
FROM   Persons
       INNER JOIN Details
         ON Persons.EmpID = Details.EmpID
WHERE  designation = 'Manager'
```

As for best source of knowledge, you can't beat books, MSDN, and StackOverFlow if you ask me. There's a good few blogs around too - but they tend to be for more advanced topics. The writers tend to hang around SO anyway!

Answer (score 0):

The query you're looking for:

```
select t1.firstname, t1.lastname
from person t1 inner join
details t2 on t1.empid = t2.empid
where t2.designation = 'Manager'
```

As for learning Sql on the internet, i dont really know a great place for tutorials, but since you're using sql server 2008 i suggest you often consult the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510741). If you're motivated you can find very indepth information there.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know specifically if this works for SQL Server 2008, but this should be rather standard SQL:

```
SELECT firstname, lastname
FROM Persons
INNER JOIN Details ON Persons.empid = Details.empid
WHERE Details.designation = 'Manager'
```

Comment: `Did` isn't the name of the table - that's the primary key column on the `Details` table ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```sql
Select p.fname, p.lname
from persons p, details d
where d.designation="Manager" and p.empid=d.empid
```

Using the single character thing, `p.` and `d.`, is a way of just doing shorthand and save typing.

And as for SQL source, I am a big fan of tizag. Usually one of my main goto's for PHP, SQL, and anything, really. W3 first, Stack Overflow second, and tizag third. I always find the answer that way.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - you shouldn't just use a comma-separated list of tables..... use **proper ANSI JOIN syntax** (`INNER JOIN`, `LEFT OUTER JOIN`) instead.